# Cron (cronie) throws syntax error but works manualy

Tags: python, sqlite, cron

This is my first time trying to use cron, I want it to pull data from a database and if the conditions are met return something. I am using flask with sqlalchemy.

Been searching the web and have found similar errors but not something that works for me.

```
import sqlite3
import datetime

connection = sqlite3.connect('sms_agenda/users.db')
cursor = connection.cursor()
cursor.execute("SELECT phone, timezone FROM user;")
result = cursor.fetchall()
now = datetime.datetime.utcnow()
now_str = str(now)[11:13]
for phone, timezone in result:
    if int(now_str) + int(timezone) == 20:
        print(phone)

cursor.close()
connection.close()
```

Entering `systemctl status cronie` returns:

```
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30858]: (root) CMDOUT (import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/343.)
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30857]: (qq88) CMDOUT (import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/343.)
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30858]: (root) CMDOUT (import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/343.)
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30858]: (root) CMDOUT (/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/sms/check_send.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `(')
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30858]: (root) CMDOUT (/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/sms/check_send.py: line 6: `connection = sqlite3.connect('sms_agenda/users.db')')
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30858]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user root
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30857]: (qq88) CMDOUT (import: unable to open X server `' @ error/import.c/ImportImageCommand/343.)
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30857]: (qq88) CMDOUT (/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/sms/check_send.py: line 6: syntax error near unexpected token `(')
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30857]: (qq88) CMDOUT (/home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/sms/check_send.py: line 6: `connection = sqlite3.connect('sms_agenda/users.db')')
okt 23 10:58:01 qq88-pc CROND[30857]: pam_unix(crond:session): session closed for user qq88
```

That is what I have entered into cron:

```
* * * * * /home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/sms/check_send.py
```

FYI This is sending an sms via Twilio but for testing I just want it to print the phone.

Answer (score 0):

Try like this instead.

```sh
* * * * * /usr/bin/python3 /home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/sms/check_send.py
```

Comment: I now tried this but no success: http://fredericiana.com/2014/11/29/sqlite-error-open-database-file/

Comment: Check your `os.getcwd()`. cron isn't running the command with /home/qq88/python-virtual-environments/sms/ as its current working directory.